# Array and var dont have predefined content

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, avr, stdint

I made an Animation.cpp for my LED cube containig a 2dimensional array of uint16_t for each frame and each layer. I initialize the array in the .cpp and also have a var containing the amount of frames. But when it's running, the array seems to only have random data (from the ram) and the int w/ amount of frames is 0.

link to cpp:
http://hastebin.com/kunemopece.avrasm

link to header:
http://hastebin.com/duvijipeya.vala

I'm pretty much a beginner in CPP/GCC, so, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Your members and global variables are unrelated (they just share the same names).

Comment: how do i make them relate? add public as prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11, you may directly do that:

```
class Animation
{
public:
    std::uint16_t frames[8][4] = {
        {0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF},
        {0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF},
        {0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF},
        {0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF},
        {0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF},
        {0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF},
        {0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF},
        {0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF}
    };
    std::uint8_t currentFrame = 0;
};
```

In C++03, you have to use the constructor:

```
class Animation
{
public:
    Animation() : currentFrame(0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != 8; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != 4; ++j) {
                frames[i][j] = 0xFFFF;
            }
        }
    }

    uint16_t frames[8][4];
    uint8_t currentFrame;
};
```

Comment: if i use the public: in the cpp it always says "expected unqualified-id before 'public'"

Comment: is there a way to do this in lower versions?

Answer (score 1):

Definition of `frames` in your class is different set of `frames` that you define in cpp.
Try initialising your frames in `Animation` class constructor.